# Primefaces 5.0 datascroller and pagination

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a a primefaces datascroller that I use to show a simple list and a set of filters that can filter that list.

Everything is on RequestScoped beans, I'm trying to avoid view/session beans because it's a b2c site and is supposed to have lots of visitors.

My problem is that when I filter the list everything is ok, but when i scroll down filter state are lost (filters are not set in the bean).

I'm almost sure that this is because datascroller is using a partial process (javax.faces.partial.execute) so that filters are not processed... but datascroller doesn't have options for that. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it in the quick and dirty way. Datascroller does not seem to have an option to send extra params.

(i changed the load function so the process sends @all instead of this.id )

```
    PF('datascroll').load= function() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.cfg.offset += this.cfg.chunkSize;
    this.loadStatus.appendTo(this.loaderContainer);
    if (this.loadTrigger) {
        this.loadTrigger.hide()
    }
    var b = this, a = {source: this.id, process: '@all', update: this.id, global: false, params: [{name: this.id + "_load", value: true}, {name: this.id + "_offset", value: this.cfg.offset}], onsuccess: function(e, c, d) {
            PrimeFaces.ajax.Response.handle(e, c, d, {widget: b, handle: function(f) {
                    this.list.append(f)
                }});
            return true
        }, oncomplete: function() {
            b.loading = false;
            b.allLoaded = (b.cfg.offset + b.cfg.chunkSize) >= b.cfg.totalSize;
            b.loadStatus.remove();
            if (b.loadTrigger && !b.allLoaded) {
                b.loadTrigger.show()
            }
        }};
    PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxRequest(a)
}
```